# Can someone help me fix my broken looped idle animation code?

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

So, in Roblox Studio, I tried making an R15 rig play an idle animation, ID:12297693014. However, the script won't work. It's a local script placed under a "Humanoid".

I tried:

```
local animationId = 12297693014
local character = script.Parent


local function playAnimation()
    character.Humanoid:PlayAnimation(animationId)
end


while true do
    playAnimation()
    wait(1)
end
```

but the rig just stayed as a T-Pose, which is what I saw before I played the game.
What's wrong with the code? And most importantly, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well buddy, looks like you're stuck in a loop that's going nowhere fast. The issue with your code is that you're telling the rig to play the animation in a loop, but you're not actually providing a stop point. So, the animation will keep playing indefinitely, leading to your T-Pose predicament.

Here's a fix:

```
local animationId = 12297693014
local character = script.Parent

local function playAnimation()
character.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(animationId):Play()
end

playAnimation()
```

This should work as a charm, but if it still doesn't, try giving your rig a break and giving it some time to rest between animations. Remember, even digital beings need a break!

Comment: I tried it out but for some weird reason, Sans, the rig, he was gliding across the floor with legs stuck in the ground, so I set the Humanoid's RigType to R6, but he did not play the animation. At least he wasn't gliding across the floor. Anyways, how do I give my rig a break?

Sorry, I'm not that good at coding.